# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter' in your configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-social-twitter

So I am following https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/ to connect my application to Twitter to get some user data. But it looks like with recent changes to `Spring boot` (version 2.0.3.RELEASE) and `Spring-social-twitter`, I am not able to execute the said article successfully. I keep getting following error:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter' in your configuration.
```

Has anyone tried the same sample with new Spring boot release? What am I missing?

Comment: looks like lot of people are facing this issue, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/issues/251

Comment: works on my machine. ;-) I upgraded my project from spring-boot 1.5.2 to 2.0.3 and the apps still start up without facing this exception. Maybe you can show us your pom, so we can start analysing...